# How to set Z-index to nested elements?

Tags: css, z-index

I have two base DOM elements and two inner elements.

- Blue box must overlap grey box.
- Blue inner box must overlap blue and grey boxes.
- Grey inner box must overlap all other elements.

But it doesn't.

```css
#grey_box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
#blue_box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #4a7497;
  background: #8daac3;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
#grey_inner_box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 200;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
#blue_inner_box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grey_box">
  <div id="grey_inner_box">grey inner</div>
</div>
<div id="blue_box">
  <div id="blue_inner_box">blue inner</div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why is your blue box green and your grey box red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `z-index` from `#grey_box`. Since `#grey_box` is beneath all other divs, we dont need z-index there. This helps to bring the `#grey_inner_box` to top.

```css
#grey_box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: 10; */
}
#blue_box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #4a7497;
  background: #8daac3;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
#grey_inner_box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 200;
  margin-top: 110px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
#blue_inner_box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grey_box">
  <div id="grey_inner_box">grey inner</div>
</div>
<div id="blue_box">
  <div id="blue_inner_box">blue inner</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

What you want isn't possible.

Once you set an element to `position:` *anything except static*, it establishes a new stacking context.

Anything you set the z-index of inside it, is only positioned within it.

Take this for example:

```
<div id="box1">
    <div id="paper1"></div>
    <div id="paper2"></div>
    <div id="paper3"></div>
</div>

<div id="box2">
    <div id="paper4"></div>
    <div id="paper5"></div>
    <div id="paper6"></div>
</div>
```

Inside each box, you can put the papers in any order you like. You can put box1 on top of box2 or vice versa, but when you move a box, you take the papers inside the box with it.

If you want to overlap the papers in the different boxes, you need to take them out of the boxes first.